# CSS vertical text in table th

Tags: css

I would like to have a table like this one:

```
                 C
        F        r
        r  I  C  o
        a  t  h  a 
        n  a  i  c
        c  l  n  i
# user  e  y  a  a
- ---- -- -- -- --
1  a   1p  1p 2p 1p
- ---- -- -- -- --
2  b   1p  2p 1p 4p

...
```

I mean i need a CSS to make my table td's text vertical.

I was trying different things in the following snippet with no success:

```css
.vertical{
    width:1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
 <table>
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th class="vertical">France</th>
                                <th class="vertical">Italy</th>
                                <th class="vertical">China</th>
                                <th class="vertical">Croacia</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Hope someone can help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way of doing it is to wrap your text in a separate element and apply the width/word-wrap technique to it.

You may need to adjust the line-height to control the spacing between the letters.

```css
th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.vertical {
  width: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th><div class="vertical">France</div></th>
      <th><div class="vertical">Italy</div></th>
      <th><div class="vertical">China</div></th>
      <th><div class="vertical">Croacia</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```